# Android APP menu like Waze menu animation

Tags: android, menu

I'm starting in `Android Studio` and would like to create an app with the most beautiful main menu. Waze, in the current version (look second 0:23 in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLl7TxnGZZ8), has a menu with a very beautiful animation. I'm not asking you to teach me how to do it, just guide me how to start searching to find something that will allow me to make an animated and more beautiful menu for my app. Thank you.

Comment: jpeg doesn't show animation. Either provide a gif or link to that app

Comment: look second 0:23 in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLl7TxnGZZ8

Comment: find this = 'Circular Reveal from touch point' on this url https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations .  .... oh and just so you know, thats called a transition. https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That animation is called a circular reveal animation and there is a [backport on github](https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal). For the map animations have a look at [Nibo](https://github.com/aliumujib/Nibo)